# Swift: Avoid scrolling top 2 tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

Is there a way to stop scrolling certain cells in tableview? I want the top 2 cells in UITableView to be static and have scroll enabled on other cells. Scroll enabled property is on tableview, so it scrolls all the cells.

The top 2 cells are of height 44.0 each. I tried the below code, but it still scrolls the top 2 cells.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    isScrolling = true
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let startScrollingOffset = 88.0
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < CGFloat(startScrollingOffset)) {
        // moved to top
        isScrollDown = false
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > CGFloat(startScrollingOffset)) {
        // moved to bottom
        isScrollDown = true
    } else {
        // didn't move
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if isScrollDown == false {
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to achieve an effect like static cells that remain on top when the list scrolls, use header view property of `UITableView`, here is an example with minimum code required to make this work. Replace the headerView with whatever cells you're trying to not scroll.

```swift
class VC: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = .purple
        return headerView
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frankenstein! I am trying it now... but can viewForHeaderInSection return 2 cells for the same section?

Comment: Just add them as a subview and constraint it so that they seem like two cells above and below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be take out first two row data from your data source( may be an array) and and create a custom view with that two row data. then set the custom view in the tableviewHeader using `viewForHeaderInSection`

As you have already removed first two row your table will show the data from third entry and the first two will be in top of them as header.